# server locking up and repeating "watchdog: bug: soft lockup" error message

Tags: server, lockup, watchdog

My ubuntu server has been having issues about every other day.  It's locking up, I can't ssh in to it.  When I connect directly I see similar error messages scrolling and I'm unable to get a prompt.  The only fix is a hard shut down followed by booting from live media and running fsck -y on my boot and operating system partitions.  I snapped a couple of pictures of the error messages this last time.  Something that's catching my eye is:

```
watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU....
```

with a little googling it seems to be a common issue locking up ubuntu with possibly many causes.  The pics of my error messages are below.  does anyone spot what the issue might be and can you suggest how to fix?

error screen 1:

[image]

error screen 2:
[image]

Comment: By hard shutdown are you saying you can't do a clean shutdown using SysRq commands direct to kernel (ie. kernel panic situation).  Did you explore logs for your *unstated* Ubuntu Server product?  Which Server system are you using? Ubuntu Core server? Ubuntu Server? what release of that *unstated* Ubuntu Server product?  What was in the systemd journals prior to your *hard shut down* or was it a kernel panic (*thus the SysRq failed to allow clean shutdown?*)

Comment: @guiverc by "hard shutdown" I mean I held the power button in until it turned off because when I connected my hdmi, keyboard, and mouse directly to the server it was unresponsive to the usb keyboard or mouse and I just saw it scroll through the error messages posted above over and over.  Is there a way for me to explore the logs after I reboot from live media and run fsck -y on the operating system partitions?  also is there any keyboard command I can try when it's unresponsive to snap it out of the loop, like in windows ctrl+alt+delete?

Comment: If you can't recall what the linux keystrokes are; just grab a phone and search `magic sysrq`, the wikipedia article is usually near top & good enough, as it bypasses any GUI/UI allowing you to direct linux kernel directly. Sysrq being a key on IBM compatible keyboards since original IBM PC in 1981; some modern keyboards don't have it printed on them (it was printed on front of key, not top) & do require an extra FN key sometimes to achieve it, but it's there on almost all but apple keyboards. It does require real keyboard (so no onscreen keyboards on phones etc)

Comment: Some commands (like `dmesg`) will only show logs of current session; thus if you reboot they're gone, however systemd journals (`jounalctl`) allows you to scan back for days/weeks/months. If you're needing to `fsck` you have a hardware issue, or incompatible software (ABI/API breakage as you've added software from multiple releases for example causing corruption) which should be found & fixed. We're limited to details you provide; and don't know what Ubuntu Server product you're using, (Ubuntu Core 20 [Server]? Ubuntu Server 23.10? etc)  thus can only speak generically.